# How can I edit .cmdline files?

Tags: mac

I'm setting up my Raspberry Pi on my Mac (Big Sur) using [this](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) instruction set. I'm currently on the step where I have to edit the recovery.cmdline file on the NOOBS file, but there isn't any app I could find that can edit the file, including Terminal. How can I edit .cmdline files?

Comment: Isn't that a text file?  You can use virtually any text editor to edit it.  You don't use Terminal to edit files - Terminal is the application that allows you to enter commands directly to the OS.  You would use a program like `nano`, `vi`, `vim`, etc. to edit the file.  There's no need to download Xcode for this.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal run `nano /path/to/file.cmdline`.

In Finder, right-click on the file icon and open with `TextEdit.app`